# Xtext: Boolean feature consuming a token series

Tags: grammar, xtext

as you know, it is possible to make a boolean feature like

```
tokenExist ?= 'TOKEN'?
```

How can i know consume more than one token like this:

```
tokensExist ?= ('TOKENONE' 'TOKENTWO')?
```

This is not valid in Xtext.

My current solution approach looks like this:

```
(tokensExist ?='TOKENONE' 'TOKENTWO')?
```

works, but does not really express what is meant

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is ok. You save the presence of the first (or any other) token in the sequence to the `tokensExist` boolean field. The presence and order of the other tokens are guaranteed by the parser.